# How to extract p-values from lmekin objects in coxme package

Tags: r

I want to be able to view the p-values for the lmekin object produced by the coxme package.

eg.

```
model= lmekin(formula = height ~ score + sex + age + (1 | IID), data = phenotype_df, varlist = kinship_matrix)
```

I tried:

```
summary(model)
coef(summary(model))
summary(model$coefficient$fixed)
fixef(model)/ sqrt(diag(vcov(model)) #(Calculates Z-scores but not p-values)
```

But these did not work.  So how do I view the p-values for this linear mixed model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took me ages of searching to figure this out, but I noticed a lot of other similar questions without proper answers, so I wanted to answer this.

You use:

```
library(coxme)
print(model)
```

- Note it is important to load the coxme package beforehand or it will not work.

I've also noticed a lot of posts about how to extract the p-value from `lmekin` objects, or how to extract the p-value from coxme objects in general.  I wrote this function, which is based on the `coxme:::print.coxme` function code (to view code type `coxme:::print.coxme` directly into R).  `print` calculates p-values on the fly - this function allows the extraction of p-values and saves them to an object.

Note that `mod` is your model, eg. `mod <- lmekin(y~x+a+b)`
Use `print(mod)` to double check that the tables match.

```
extract_coxme_table <- function (mod){
    beta <- mod$coefficients$fixed
    nvar <- length(beta)
    nfrail <- nrow(mod$var) - nvar
    se <- sqrt(diag(mod$var)[nfrail + 1:nvar])
    z<- round(beta/se, 2)
    p<- signif(1 - pchisq((beta/se)^2, 1), 2)
    table=data.frame(cbind(beta,se,z,p))
    return(table)
}
```

Comment: I had to replace the first line of the function with `beta <- fixef(mod)`.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this topic because I was looking for the same thing for just the `coxme` object. The function of IcedCoffee works with a micro adjustment:

```
    extract_coxme_table <- function (mod){
        beta <- mod$coefficients #$fixed is not needed
        nvar <- length(beta)
        nfrail <- nrow(mod$var) - nvar
        se <- sqrt(diag(mod$var)[nfrail + 1:nvar])
        z<- round(beta/se, 2)
        p<- signif(1 - pchisq((beta/se)^2, 1), 2)
        table=data.frame(cbind(beta,se,z,p))
        return(table)
    }
```