# How to find the source code of R package functions

Tags: r

### Context

I'm trying to put a function written by someone else in my own R package but I'm having some problems.

### Question

The problem is that the code that calculates `std.error` gives an error, but when I load the `coxme` package, the error goes away.

I can't use `library(coxme)` when writing R package functions. Please tell me how I can successfully calculate `std.error`.

### Reproduciable code

A reproducible example is as follows:

```
library(survival)
# fit a coxme model
fit <- coxme::coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + (1|inst), lung)

# estimate,nvar and nfrail are for calculating std.error
estimate <- coxme::fixef(fit)
nvar <- base::length(estimate)
nfrail <- base::nrow(fit$var) - nvar
```

```
std.error <- base::sqrt(diag(fit$var)[nfrail + 1:nvar])
# Error in as.integer(x) : 
#  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'
```

When the `coxme` package is loaded, `std.error` can be successfully computed.

```
library(coxme)
std.error <- base::sqrt(diag(fit$var)[nfrail + 1:nvar]) # Running successfully
```

### What I've done

1. I thought that the `diag()` function might come from the `coxme` package, but after I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752002/how-to-view-the-source-code-of-functions-that-are-not-exported-in-the-r-package) at stackoverflow, I found out that the `diag()` function in the `coxme` package is from the `base` package.
2. For the code to calculate `std.error` I refer to this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720261/11636376

Comment: "I can't use library(coxme) when writing R package functions".  That's true, unless you have constraints you've not told us about.  As you say yourself, "the `diag()` function in the `coxme` package is from the `base` package".

Comment: Gah!  I meant "that's *NOT* true".  Curse the five minute edit rule!

Comment: Thanks @Limey, even if I specify `base::diag()` it still returns an error.

Comment: Use `bdsmatrix::diag(fit$variance)`. (because `class(fit$variance)` returns an object of class `"bdsmatrix"`. Then run `?bdsmatrix::`bdsmatrix-class` and find the S4 method `diag`.